# MySQLi & fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) Returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In phpMyAdmin, I can use the following SQL without errors, and I get a table with 3 entries:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_orders WHERE 1
```

However, when I run this php code:

```
$quickDbConn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
$result = $quickDbConn->query('SELECT * FROM ticket_orders WHERE 1');

var_dump($quickDbConn);
var_dump($quickDbConn->client_info);
var_dump($quickDbConn->client_version);
var_dump($quickDbConn->info);
var_dump($result);
var_dump(!!$result);
var_dump(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));

$quickDbConn->close();
```

I get the following output:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(3) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.30" ["client_version"]=> int(50530) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["host_info"]=> string(23) "xx.xx.xxx.xx via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.30" ["server_version"]=> int(50530) ["stat"]=> string(144) "Uptime: 156684 Threads: 1 Questions: 2835826 Slow queries: 36 Opens: 19439 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 64 Queries per second avg: 18.099" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(74151) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

string(6) "5.5.30"

int(50530)

NULL

object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(3) ["type"]=> int(0) }

bool(true)

int(1)
```

Can anyone explain to me why `$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` is returning nothing?  Or how I can fix this?

Comment: "Available only with mysqlnd."

Comment: We don't actually see the result of `fetch_all`. The last output shown is that of `var_dump(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

Comment: exactly - `var_dump($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));` returns nothing - not null, not false - just a blank line

Comment: No, it wouldn't do that. This means `var_dump` isn't running at all, and the only way that would happen is if a fatal error occurred. How are your error reporting settings and/or error logs…?

Comment: It is _impossible_ for var_dump to return “nothing at all” - except for when your script doesn’t even get that far. Enable proper PHP error reporting, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because fetch_all work only with [mysqlnd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php). However if you want to get query result as enumerated array and associative array at the same time, you have to use fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) that would do.
[fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: You are right - this wouldn't work because mysqlnd wasn't installed on this version of PHP - I was unable to recompile or upgrade PHP so in the end I had to find a completely different solution :(